# How to make a slide in a carousel load when a page element is clicked?

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

I have some tournament brackets which are built using [a jQuery plugin](http://www.aropupu.fi/bracket/jquery-bracket/dist/jquery.bracket.min.js).

This plugin creates a bunch of hierarchical trees which are basically divs displaying players and matches data. On the top of the page I used an Owl carousel to load videos of those matches. What I am trying to do is have this behaviour in the page:

Match in the bracket is clicked => Relevant video is loaded in the carousel.

I managed to create links in a certain area above the brackets once every match is clicked. Those links are clickable and they do get this behaviour.

However, what I want next is to make this behaviour invisible, so that when you click one div from the brackets, a specific video is loaded in the Owl carousel, without any visible link being created. Please mind that the way the Owl carousel works with videos is by using some callbacks and URL data hashes, so it seems the plugin requires some links to be created or present in the page for the carousel to serve the relevant content. You can see how this works in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EwFMn/9/

What I have tried until now (I've tried all the methods listed on this question here and otherwise) was to use `window.location`, but this will open a new tab in the browser, which I don't want. So, I guess the question TLDR is:

**How can one create invisible links with jQuery which are clicked after a certain element in the page is clicked, without opening a new tab in the browser?**

(I would post a fiddle, but there is so much code and libraries loaded, it would probably discourage anyone from taking a look at it. So just consider the general jQuery question.)

Comment: why can't you use the events available in plugin API?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? I don't claim I know each of these plugins very well. The brackets plugin only provides two behaviours: onhover and onclick which make matches data display on top of the brackets. I'm not aware of any more built-in tools. Basically the difficulty in making this work is making the carousel plugin work with the brackets one, by using jQuery to find the clicked match, create a link very fast in the same area, click it and destroy it. That's how I see this should work, because Owl carousel requires links for the callbacks to work.